# Laravel Polymorphic Relation Doesn't Get the Type Automatically

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relationship

I have 3 tables; receipts, obsolescence, and stock. Stock can have receipt and obsolescence.
recipt table:
id: integer

obsolescence table:
id: int

stock table:
id: int
transaction_id: int
transaction_type: string

stock model:

```
class Stocks extends Model
{
 use HasFactory;
 protected $fillable =[
     'model_id',
     'model_name', 
 ];

 public function transaction()
 {
     return $this->morphTo();
 }

}
```

receipt model:

```
class Receipt extends Model
{
 use HasFactory;
 

 public function trans()
 {
     return $this->morphMany(Stocks::class, 'transaction');
 }

}
```

receipt model:

```
class Obsolescence extends Model
{
 use HasFactory;
 

 public function trans()
 {
     return $this->morphMany(Stocks::class, 'transaction');
 }

}
```

But whenever I create data it does not get the model name and gives the error of transaction_type is not set.

Comment: Are you trying to add data into the database or retrieve data?

Comment: Transaction_type should either hold `app/Models/Receipt` or `app/Models/Obsolescence`

Comment: Yes it should, but it does not get the value automatically, and throws an error: transaction_type not set

Comment: It gets the transaction_id, but not the transaction_type

Comment: How are you setting the transaction_type?